# error syntax error at or near ":" for split_part () of createNativeQuery in spring boot for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, placeholder, nativequery

I'm getting SQL exception while executing the query which contains

```
split_part() method as split_part(value::TEXT,':', 1).
```

```
String queryStr = " select split_part(value::TEXT,':', 1) from table";

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
List results = query.getResultList();
```

```
ERROR 2020-02-10 14:54:37,926 [http-nio-7070-exec-1] 142 - ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 855
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your obfuscation layer probably chokes on the `::` operator. Use the `cast()` operator instead:

```
String queryStr = " select split_part(cast(value as text),':', 1) from table";
```

But why do you think you need the cast to begin with? If you are storing `:` characters that column, it is most probably a `text` (or `varchar`) column anyway and you don't need a cast at all.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name - You are correct that is not required cast into TEXT. I removed it is working fine. Thanks a lot.